# Использование Comparator и обращение в методе compare к полям класса

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему метод compare не видит переменную `b` класса `TwoString`:

```
public class TwoString implements Comparable <TwoString> {

    public String a;
    public String b;

    TwoString (String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int compareTo (TwoString another) {
        return (this.a).compareTo(another.a);
    }

    public String toString () {
        return a + (" = ") + b;
    }

    //Ошибка: cannot find symbol b:
    class StrComp <TwoString> implements Comparator <TwoString> {
        public int compare (TwoString first, TwoString sec) {
           return (first.b).compareTo(sec.b);
        }
    }   

    //Если заменить реализацию выше на:
    static final Comparator<TwoString> StrComp = new Comparator<TwoString>() {
            public int compare(TwoString ts1, TwoString ts2) {
                return (ts1.b).compareTo(ts2.b);
            }
    };
    //Код компилируется без проблем.
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: `class StrComp <TwoString>` - здесь не надо TwoString, просто `class StrComp implements Comparator<TwoString>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас 2 разных класса реализуют один интерфейс, они никак не смогут увидеть друг друга. Используйте вот этот код:

```
class StrComp implements Comparator<TwoString> {

    @Override
    public int compare(TwoString first, TwoString sec) {
        return (first.b).compareTo(sec.b);

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало :) 
Неправильный синтаксис спровоцировал ошибку